# jQuery - Get highest level elements with certain class

Tags: html, jquery

I have a set of nested divs that look like this (this is just an example, the structure can vary):

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="dummy">
    <div class="target one"></div>
    <div class="dummy">
      <div class="target two">
        <div class="dummy"></div>
        <div class="target three"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="target four"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I now want to select the `<div>`s with classes `one`, `two` and `four`. What I would need is a recursive selector (like `$(.container div.target)`) which aborts the search down a branch after it found an element and instead continues with the next branch.

`$(.container div.target)` selects all the targets, which is not what I want. `$(.container div.target:first-of-type)` almost does what I want; it selects `one` and `two`, but not `four`.

Is there a jQuery selector that can do what I want? If not how could I implement this behaviour in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the following code:

```
$('.container div.target').not(function () {                              
     return $(this).parents('div.target').length > 0
})
```

It uses jquery [.not()](https://api.jquery.com/not/) method to eliminate `<div class='target'>` elements having another `<div class='target'>` element somewhere up in the dom hierarchy.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {

     $('.container div.target').not(function () {                              
         return $(this).parents('div.target').length > 0
     }).each(function () {
         console.log($(this).attr('id'));
     });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="container">
        <div class="dummy">
            <div id="1" class="target one"></div>
            <div id="-1" class="dummy">
                <div id="2" class="target two">
                    <div id="-2" class="dummy"></div>
                    <div id="3" class="target three"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="4" class="target four"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So after trying out different things, I figured that writing my own function to do this would probably be the best solution. This is what I came up with:

```js
$.getHighestElements = function(startPoint, selector, child = false) {
  var elems = [];
  startPoint.children('div').each(function () {
    if($(this).hasClass(selector)) {
      elems.push($(this));
    } else {
      $.merge(elems, $.getHighestElements($(this), selector, true));
    }
  });
            
  if(child)
    return elems;
  else
    return $(elems).map(function() { return this.toArray(); });
}

const elements = $.getHighestElements($(.container), "target");
```

This returns a wrapped set of elements that can be used just like any other jquery wrapped set.

Comment: why don't use .filter()?

Comment: Because I'm bad at jQuery